# Copy DataGridView values to TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have tried to get an answer to this but so far no help has been able to do what I want it to.

I have this piece of code, which is meant to look at the selected row and output it's columns into the corresponding text boxes.

```
 private void DataGridView01_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (DataGridView01.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
       personIDTextBox.Text = DataGridView01.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
       comboBox1.Text = DataGridView01.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
       Txt_FirstName.Text = DataGridView01.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       mIDDLENAMETextBox.Text = DataGridView01.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
       sURNAMETextBox.Text = DataGridView01.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
       cITYTextBox.Text = DataGridView01.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
       eMAILTextBox.Text = DataGridView01.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
     }
  }
```

When I launch the program, I get no errors but it doesn't output the data into the textbox. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You do select a row, right? - Also: There seems to be one curly to many in your code; ae you sure it is as written??

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint to see what's the value of  DataGridView01.SelectedRows.Count?

Comment: @TaW Yes, I do select a row.......

I have put a breakpoint and tried testing that but it just says "The name DataGridView01 does not exist in the current context.

Comment: That sounds fishy! How could that be without the compiler complaining..?? The 1st breakpoint should go on the if

Comment: @TaW I am unsure, I am fairly new to C# and Visual Studio. The extra curly was just a copy and paste error. I have no clue what i've done wrong. Everything I have read says that this code should work. The breakpoint is on the if.

Comment: Indeed, it does look ok; so you do hit the if with the debugger and can step on or does it complain about the DGV??

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by the DGV? But when I press the start button, the program launches like normal, my DataGridView01 gets populated with the information from the SQL connection but when I click a row nothing changes. @TaW

Comment: DGV is just a short hand for DataGRidView. What is its `SelectionMode`? Maybe it doesn't get selected beause of that? There are a few and if any cell click shall select do use `FullRowSelect`!

Comment: @TaW I am using FullRowSelect.

Comment: So the row gets blue? Then the event is not __hooked up__?

Comment: Yes, the full row does turn blue. Could you please elaborate on "not hooked up" as I said I am fairly new.

Comment: If you have to ask that chances are that you have just copied the code without _hooking it up_. See my answer, which is a little too long for comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HOOKING UP EVENTS:

It is the most basic thing you need to learn to code in VS. In short it means that the event name, here `DataGridView01_SelectionChanged` is connected to the event. To do so one can either use code or one inserts it into the correct slot of the events pane of the property tab. Select the `DataGridView`, open the events pane (the one with the flash) and locate the SelectionChanged event! Here insert the name of the event and you are done.

[image]

(I only have the German versions of VS installed..)

The result is reflected in the form_designer.cs file and it is the same thing (in reverse) as double clicking that spot and then filling in the generated code stub..

Controls have many events; one is the **default** event and this can be generated by **double clicking** the control itself in the designer. But eventually you will need all 3 ways to **generate** and **hook up** the events, (as well as sometimes removing them.)

Comment: Hmm, I am unsure where the events pane is? I have tried looking but I don't see one with a yellow flash.

Comment: It is one of the panes along with the properties pane, usually at the right botton, and the flash is not yellow in all VS versions, see the screenshot!

Comment: Thank you, this is now working. I am just curious as to why tutorials don't cover this? I have read over 20 different ones and have never come across this.

Comment: Now I am curious how I can populate the combo box with the right selection as it's "DrowDownList".

Comment: That is a new question; as usual first google and read up on a few SO answers there; try a little code and __when and if__ you don't succeed write a new question!

Answer (score 0):

I use a slightly different approach when trying to get data from a datagridview.

Try doing `personIDTextBox.Text = DataGridView01.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();`

but instead of the event being on selection change, switch to `CellClick` and change the property of the the datagridview row selection property to full row select. after that you can change the `SelectedCell[0]` number to match whichever cell you want

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but with that, I am getting DataGridView does not contain a definition for SelectedCell.

Comment: Sorry, i just spotted a typo in what I wrote - `SelectedCells[0]` is the method (plural, not singular). Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the datagridview selected rows into corresponding textboxes, fine the below steps ,

**Step 1:** 
1. Change the DataGridView Selection mode to **FullRowSelect** in Datagridview property.
2. Create the cell click event in Data grid view using property.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6RaI.jpg)
3. Write the below code and test it, It may helpful

```
private void DataGridView01_CellClick(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
if (DataGridView01.Rows.Count > -1)
{
PersonIdTextBox.Text=DataGridView01.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
comboBox1.Text = DataGridView01.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
Txt_FirstName.Text = DataGridView01.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
 mIDDLENAMETextBox.Text = DataGridView01.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
sURNAMETextBox.Text = DataGridView01.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
cITYTextBox.Text = DataGridView01.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
eMAILTextBox.Text = DataGridView01.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();

}
}
```