# ListView DrawColumnHeader is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have the following method to set background color and Font for the list view's column headers but it is not working. Anybody can help me?

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        // Store the column text alignment, letting it default
        // to Left if it has not been set to Center or Right.
        switch (e.Header.TextAlign)
        {
            case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                break;
            case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                break;
        }

        // Draw the standard header background.
        e.DrawBackground();

        // Draw the header text.
        using (Font headerFont = new Font("Helvetica", 25, FontStyle.Bold)) //Font size!!!!
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, headerFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, sf);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

It doesn't matter I use this method or not. It remains same. Nothing changes. 
Is it because of properties of the list view?

Comment: _Is not working_ is not enough! Please explain/describe the problem!! Also tag for Winforms, if it is!

Comment: Have you set `OwnerDraw = true;` ???

Comment: Thanks buddy. "OwnerDraw = true" fixed it .

Comment: But this time, list view becomes empty. It must contain my list view items??

Comment: Lol. Indeed. You need to add the other two events, see my answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks ok. If it doesn't do anything you have forgotten to set the `OwnerDraw` property to `true`.

This also means that you **need** to add code for the **other two** draw events. The default actions will do:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}


private void listView1_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

Don't forget to [hook up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=1|0.3904#33276161) the events ;-)

Comment: @a-f-a When an answer helped you solve the problem and you accepted it, you can also kindly consider [voting it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), while it is not compulsory, but it is reasonable :)

Comment: Yeah. I will learn this kind of things in time. I am new here :)