# Show Transparent Loading Spinner above other Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, gdi+

I am working in a spinner control. I want the control to support transparent backcolor. When the arc is drawn, there is a blank space in the middle, I want that space to be truly transparent, so that I could put another control behind it and it would not be covered by the spinner.

I tried overriding the CreateParams void.
Also I set the style to support TransparentColor.
Tried overriding OnPaintBackground void, but I cannot achieve the real transparent backcolor.

So, what can you suggest me to do?

Comment: You can see a transparent spinner in this post. [Why does the designer slowing when two custom controls has timer added?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195226/why-does-the-designer-slowing-when-two-custom-controls-has-timer-added?)  The same technique is described hereto make a transparent picture box and label. [How to make two transparent layer with c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099017/how-to-make-two-transparent-layer-with-c)

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Saw both posts but I could not get a true transparency. I also duplicated the SpinningCircles control from the first post you linked. But that one doesn't achieve a real transparent backcolor.

Comment: At least for the second link which I shared, you can see the screenshot which contains transparent picture boxes and transparent labels. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: When using it in the designer or at debugging time all controls behind it get covered by a gray solid color (the form's backcolor

Comment: I checked it again and It works properly in both designer and run-time. Probably you have set a color as `BackColor` of it. You should set `Transparent` as `BackColor`.

Comment: Y es I'm sure I have set  the control's backcolor to Transparent (in the designer and in the code)

Comment: I'm talking about `TranparentPictureBox` and `TransparentLabel` which I shared. I don't have any idea about your code. But at least, I'm sure if you understand an apply the approach, you can have a transparent spinner simply. Hope you find those answers helpful :)

Comment: Also when creating a spinner using an arc, you can simply exclude the center region from the region of your control. For example, take a look at this example [How to create a User Control with rounded corners?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32991419/3110834)

Comment: By the way, I also made the spinning circle control work properly by some small changes in the linked code.

Comment: Oh ok so let me make another approach with the second link code. Then I will tell you the results

Comment: I posted 2 good options for showing transparent spinner above other controls. Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Answer (score 24):

To make a transparent layer, you should override painting of the control and draw the control in this order, *First* draw all controls in the same container which are under your control (based on z-index) on a bitmap.
*Then* draw that bitmap on graphics of your control.
*At last* draw content of your control.
*Also* the [`BackColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) of your control should be `Color.Transparent`.

Also as another option to make transparent layer, you can exclude some regions from your control when drawing.

In the following samples I used the first technique and created 2 controls. A [spinning circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195226/why-does-the-designer-slowing-when-two-custom-controls-has-timer-added?) transparent control. and a [transparent picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099017/how-to-make-two-transparent-layer-with-c) control.

In both samples I used a delay between loading rows to showing a spinner make sense.

**Sample 1 - Using a SpinningCircles Control**

`SpinningCircles` control draws circles and supports transparency. The control doesn't animate at design-time, but it animates at run-time. Also it doesn't consume resources when it is not visible.

[image]

**Sample 2 - Using a TransparentPictureBox Control and a transparent animated gif**
`TransparentPictureBox` control supports transparency, so I used an animated gif as its image and as you can see, the gif is showing correctly.

[image]

**Sample 1 Code - SpinningCircles**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class SpinningCircles : Control
{
    int increment = 1;
    int radius = 4;
    int n = 8;
    int next = 0;
    Timer timer;
    public SpinningCircles()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => this.Invalidate();
        if (!DesignMode)
            timer.Enabled = true;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                 ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                 ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                 ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parent != null && this.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
        {
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(Parent.Width, Parent.Height))
            {
                Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                      .Where(c => Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c) > Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(this))
                      .Where(c => c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.Bounds))
                      .OrderByDescending(c => Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c))
                      .ToList()
                      .ForEach(c => c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.Bounds));

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, -Left, -Top);
            }
        }
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        int length = Math.Min(Width, Height);
        PointF center = new PointF(length / 2, length / 2);
        int bigRadius = length / 2 - radius - (n - 1) * increment;
        float unitAngle = 360 / n;
        if (!DesignMode)
            next++;
        next = next >= n ? 0 : next;
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = next; i < next + n; i++)
        {
            int factor = i % n;
            float c1X = center.X + (float)(bigRadius * Math.Cos(unitAngle * factor * Math.PI / 180));
            float c1Y = center.Y + (float)(bigRadius * Math.Sin(unitAngle * factor * Math.PI / 180));
            int currRad = radius + a * increment;
            PointF c1 = new PointF(c1X - currRad, c1Y - currRad);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, c1.X, c1.Y, 2 * currRad, 2 * currRad);
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White, 2))
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, c1.X, c1.Y, 2 * currRad, 2 * currRad);
            a++;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = Visible;
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    }
}
```

**Sample 2 Code - TransparentPictureBox Code**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class TransparentPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public TransparentPictureBox()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parent != null && this.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
        {
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(Parent.Width, Parent.Height))
            {
                Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                      .Where(c => Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c) > Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(this))
                      .Where(c => c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.Bounds))
                      .OrderByDescending(c => Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c))
                      .ToList()
                      .ForEach(c => c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.Bounds));

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, -Left, -Top);
            }
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty old question, but it would be great if you can verify the answer or let me know if you have any problem using the solutions :)

Comment: How to call it ?

Comment: @Moeez Just have an instance of the control positioned properly on the form, then show it (and update it) and hide it whenever you need. For example take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142535/3110834).

Answer (score 2):

I slightly changed Reza's code (SpinningCircles) to add a semi-transparent background. I wanted to share it with you.
(NOTE: The spinner length was fixed to 100 and should be added as a component property)

```
public partial class WorkingPanel : UserControl
{
    #region Constants
    private static readonly Int32 kSpinnerLength = 100;
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private Int32 increment = 1;
    private Int32 radius = 4;
    private Int32 n = 8;
    private Int32 next = 0;
    private Timer timer = null;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public WorkingPanel()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(100, 100);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => this.Invalidate();

        if (!DesignMode)
            timer.Enabled = true;

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                 ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                 ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                 ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods (Protected - Override)
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != Parent && (this.BackColor.A != 255 || this.BackColor == Color.Transparent))
        {
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(Parent.Width, Parent.Height))
            {
                Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                      .Where(c => Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c) > Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(this))
                      .Where(c => c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.Bounds))
                      .OrderByDescending(c => Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c))
                      .ToList()
                      .ForEach(c => c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.Bounds));

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, -Left, -Top);

                if (this.BackColor != Color.Transparent)
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
            }
        }

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        Int32 length = kSpinnerLength;
        PointF center = new PointF(Width / 2, Height / 2);
        Int32 bigRadius = length / 2 - radius - (n - 1) * increment;
        float unitAngle = 360 / n;

        if (!DesignMode)
            next++;

        next = next >= n ? 0 : next;
        Int32 a = 0;
        for (Int32 i = next; i < next + n; i++)
        {
            Int32 factor = i % n;
            float c1X = center.X + (float)(bigRadius * Math.Cos(unitAngle * factor * Math.PI / 180));
            float c1Y = center.Y + (float)(bigRadius * Math.Sin(unitAngle * factor * Math.PI / 180));
            Int32 currRad = radius + a * increment;
            PointF c1 = new PointF(c1X - currRad, c1Y - currRad);

            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, c1.X, c1.Y, 2 * currRad, 2 * currRad);

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White, 2))
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, c1.X, c1.Y, 2 * currRad, 2 * currRad);

            a++;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = Visible;

        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: How do you have implemented it? Creating the class and writing the following code does not show it:

`using(var F = new SpinningCircle())
{
   F.Show(); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
}`

Comment: I just added the WorkingPanel to the form and voila.  After that you can set the anchors or dock properties to fill the whole form.

Answer (score 1):

Modification from CrApHeR's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49678175/3079753) to add `Designer Properties`

[image: preview]

### How to use

Add this class to your project

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class Spinner : Control
{
    private int next = 0;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public Spinner()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

        Size = new Size(100, 100);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        timer.Tick += (s, e) => Invalidate();
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public int NodeCount { get; set; } = 8;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public int NodeRadius { get; set; } = 4;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public float NodeResizeRatio { get; set; } = 1.0f;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public Color NodeFillColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public Color NodeBorderColor { get; set; } = Color.White;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public int NodeBorderSize { get; set; } = 2;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public int SpinnerRadius { get; set; } = 100;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != Parent && (BackColor.A != 255 || BackColor == Color.Transparent))
        {
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Parent.Width, Parent.Height))
            {
                foreach (Control control in GetIntersectingControls(Parent))
                {
                    control.DrawToBitmap(bmp, control.Bounds);
                }

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, -Left, -Top);

                if (BackColor != Color.Transparent)
                {
                    using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, Width, Height);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        PointF center = new PointF(Width / 2, Height / 2);
        int bigRadius = (int)(SpinnerRadius / 2 - NodeRadius - (NodeCount - 1) * NodeResizeRatio);
        float unitAngle = 360 / NodeCount;

        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            next++;
        }

        next = next >= NodeCount ? 0 : next;

        for (int i = next, a = 0; i < next + NodeCount; i++, a++)
        {
            int factor = i % NodeCount;
            float c1X = center.X + (float)(bigRadius * Math.Cos(unitAngle * factor * Math.PI / 180));
            float c1Y = center.Y + (float)(bigRadius * Math.Sin(unitAngle * factor * Math.PI / 180));
            int currRad = (int)(NodeRadius + a * NodeResizeRatio);
            PointF c1 = new PointF(c1X - currRad, c1Y - currRad);

            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(NodeFillColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, c1.X, c1.Y, 2 * currRad, 2 * currRad);
            }

            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White, NodeBorderSize))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, c1.X, c1.Y, 2 * currRad, 2 * currRad);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = Visible;
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    }

    private IOrderedEnumerable<Control> GetIntersectingControls(Control parent)
    {
        return parent.Controls.Cast<Control>()
            .Where(c => parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c) > parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(this))
            .Where(c => c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Bounds))
            .OrderByDescending(c => parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(c));
    }
}
```

Drag the `Spinner` control from the `Toolbox` to your Form

[image: toolbox]

Alternatively, you can add it at runtime with this code

```cs
Spinner spinner = new Spinner();
spinner.Location = new Point(50, 50);
Controls.Add(spinner);
```

Then, you can change its properties from the `Designer Properties` category `Appearance`

[image: properties]

The main properties you may want to customize are:

- NodeCount (default: 8)
- NodeRadius (default: 4)
- NodeResizeRatio (default: 1.0f)
- NodeFillColor (default: Black)
- NodeBorderColor (default: White)
- NodeBorderSize (default: 2)
- SpinnerRadius (default: 100)
- BackColor (default: Transparent) (supports alpha transparency)

  ```cs
  BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Blue.R, Color.Blue.G, Color.Blue.B))
  ```