# How to show waiting Gif image during form load event

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, async-await, thread-synchronization

i have one form which is doing some long process on form load event,
So i want to show One Gif image "Please Wait" during form load event.

below is code.

```
private void frmWaitShow()
        {
            try
            {
                frmWaitwithstatus objWait = new frmWaitwithstatus();// this form has Gif Image for Processing
                objWait.lblStatus.Text = "Processing Request, Please wait...";
                objWait.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.SystemException(ex);
                Logger.FTSError(" ERROR :" + ex.Message + "frmTest || frmWaitShow");

            }
        }


        Thread oThread;
        private void frmTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


                oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(frmWaitShow));
                oThread.Start();

                //Functions for Connection with devices
                if (LoadDatafromDB() == false) return;
                if (ElectTestLoad() == false) return;
                if (PowerOnSelfTest() == false) { return; }
                InitiControlsElectTest();
                SetSystemMode(SystemMode.ElectricalMode);

                oThread.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                oThread.Abort();
                Logger.SystemException(ex);

            }
        }
```

after Thread.start() my debugger go one one step in each thread main and one i created but after it go to below line.

frmWaitwithstatus.cs constructor first line

```
public frmWaitwithstatus()
```

it stop execute my Thread and execute all function of main thread once Main Thread execution complete after then only it start execute my thread (which is Gif processing image).

Comment: Use Tasks and follow the async/await path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: @MickyD No its not. i know how to handle UI controls on different Thread, here i am calling separate form which has GIF image from the thread.

Comment: You clearly don't with your code riddled with so many mistakes. You are clearly attempting to update UI from a worker thread; showing a dialog from a MTA thread; blocking your worker thread and last but not least, ending the thread ungratefully by calling abort.

Comment: [Show Loading animation during loading data in other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142535/3110834)

Comment: [Show Transparent Loading Spinner above other Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37473192/3110834)

Answer (score 1):

Using the **async/await** pattern will made this an easy task and every form will work on UI thread:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // async show loading form dialog
        var loadingForm = new LoadingForm();
        var loadingDialogTask = this.InvokeAsync(loadingForm.ShowDialog);

        // async loading data
        var data = await LoadDataAsync();
        listBox1.DataSource = data;

        loadingForm.Close();
        await loadingDialogTask;
    }

    private async Task<ICollection<string>> LoadDataAsync()
    {
        // fake work load
        await Task.Delay(4000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Enumerable.Range(1,20000).Select(e => e.ToString()).ToList();
    }

}
```

Needed async extension for the controls:

```
public static class ControlAsyncExtensions
{
    public static Task InvokeAsync(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        control.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                action();
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
        }
        ));
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static Task<T> InvokeAsync<T>(this Control control, Func<T> action)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        control.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                tcs.SetResult(action());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
        }
        ));
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```