# Transparent animated gif picture show above another picture

Tags: c#, winforms, gif, picturebox, transparent

I want to show a transparent animated gif picture above another picture in a WinForm.
But the problem is animated gif image is not transparent & has a white background.
How can i make that animated gif transparent?

---

Here is my animated gif (It has a transparent background):

[image: animated gif]

And here is my orange picture :

[image: orange picture]

And here is my winform after load :

[image: Transparent animated gif picture above another picture]

As you see `Loading...` image has white background.
How can i transparent it?

---

**THIS IS NOT DUPLICATE, THE ANSWER [HERE][4] DID N'T SOLVE MY PROBLEM.**   
**PLEASE TEST MY ANIMATED GIF & YOU WILL SEE WHAT AM I SAYING!**

Comment: Your gif just worked fine for me. Is your picturebox is in another control? And as you mentioned `pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` didn't work for you?

Comment: Gif doesn't really support transparency.

Comment: @TaW So what should i do?

Comment: Not sure. - You could change the gif to an orange background (in a gif editor) or draw the animation yourself or forget about the glitz.. Or maybe one could set your orange to be the transparency color of the gif; but I don't know if that is supported in animated gifs

Comment: @Muhammad Hannan I have a panel. I've added "PictureBox1 = Orange Image" to that panel. (Dock = Filled). Then I've added "PictureBox2 = Loading..." above PictureBox1. > Please see my edit > I've added orange picture.

Comment: @Muhammad Hannan didn't work for you? didn't work

Comment: You can use the [ImageAnimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageanimator) class to animate that Bitmap (it allows to specify a Point to define the the Image position). Note that this image is not intended to be shown on a background much different than White. You'll have a very bad *effect* on darker colors. Anyway, if you set all your controls to the same BackColor, it will work anyway (so you'll see what happens :).

Comment: Found the cause of issue. Actually your gif background is actually transparent but your form background is set to `white or control`. You can set the form color to match your orange background then your issue will resolve.

Comment: It is a duplicate.

Comment: @LarsTech I told you. This is not duplicate. This is about animated gif. Not png images. Read my situation carefully man.

Comment: I did.  I downloaded your gif, too.  I get an orange background.  Try those answers from the linked post and see what is different about your situation.  Otherwise, post code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech Do not use orange background. Use my Orange Picture for PictureBox1 & Loading... gif for PictureBox2. Two pictureboxes! Not one in orange background.

Comment: WinForm Controls will only be transaparent to the parent container.  Like the answer posted below and from the links, you would have to make the gif PictureBox a child of the jaxx liberty PictureBox.

Comment: you would have to make the gif PictureBox a child of the jaxx liberty PictureBox! How can i do that?

Comment: Look at the first line of code from the answer you downvoted.

Comment: It seems it works, but how can i fix this problem in design time?

Comment: Have you tried to simply use the same BackColor for all your PictureBoxes? Or set the animation as the `PictureBox.Image` property, using a single PictureBox?

Comment: PictureBox controls were designed *not* to be container controls, which is why the designer won't do your bidding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37473192/3110834

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910172/how-to-make-picturebox-transparent) works
You have to set the gif-picturebox above the other one (as child) and set it's BackColor to Transparent

```
imgBackImage.Controls.Add(imgGifImage);
imgGifImage.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

The first line of these codes is the key.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCii9.png)

Comment: How can i fix this problem in design time?