# Making the panel transparent?

Tags: winforms, .net-core

I'm creating a simple form with WinForms with dotNET7 using VS2022:

[image]

The gray rectangle is a *Panel*, which I need to make transparent. You can see a label underneath the panel, and I wish it to be visible, **while** the panel itself is brought to front.

With dotNET framework, it was so easy:

```
public class TransparentPanel : Panel
{
  protected override CreateParams CreateParams
  {
    get
    {
      var cp = base.CreateParams;
      cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
      return cp;
    }
  }

  protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    //base.OnPaintBackground(e);
  }
}
```

However, with dotNET7 and VS2022 (don't really know which one causes the limitation), when I change the Panel to "TransparentPanel", designer simply gets rid of it:

With original panel, these are my components:

[image]

After changing panel1 from `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` to `TransparentPanel`:

[image]

I tried changing panel's background to transparent, but it's not the giving me my required results:

```
this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

[image]

Also tried to apply color with alpha:

```
this.panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red);
```

[image]

So how can I achieve this very simple thing with dotNET7?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36102074/14171304

Comment: Works fine when I try it with .net6, as expected.  The "gets rid of it" problem is what you should pursue, there is no other good way to do this.  Normally that only happens when adding the control causes an exception at design-time.  That should produce a message box with the exception details, be sure to state what it says if you see it.  Another way to debug that is to start VS again and attach to DesignToolsServer.exe, force it to stop on any CLR exception.

Comment: Remove the `OnPaintBackground` override; in the Control's Constructor, add `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true)`, as shown here: [Translucent circular Control with text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435842/7444103)

Comment: I'm getting CS1540 compile error: "Cannot access protected member 'Control.SetStyle(ControlStyles, bool)' via a qualifier of type 'Panel'; the qualifier must be of type 'Form1' (or derived from it)"

Comment: That method is called from the Constructor of your `TransparentPanel` Custom Control. Just take a look at the Custom Control in the Q&A I've linked