# How to partially overlay a picturebox over form controls

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, picturebox

I want to have an image partially overlaying a winform control (in this case a datagridview) but it seems that's not working as i would.
I followed the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910172/how-to-make-picturebox-transparent) and it works fine when the parent is the control (DGV) but not when the parent is the form...
I will like to have something like this:
[image: desired]

But instead i get something like this :
[image: problematic]

Following the answer and setting the parent to DGV works fine....
[image]

Comment: Looks like the background is not transparent. Share some code what you have tried

Comment: please check in your code whether you missed that line: `b.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` from the example of your posted link

Comment: I have updated the question to answer the comment from EpicKip & Mong Zhu

Comment: Indeed, winforms does not support transparency for overlapping controls. you may workaround by using two pictureBoxes. See [here for an example using a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107257/how-to-add-label-transparency-in-picturebox-c/35107623#35107623). The trick is to nest the 2nd one and move it to the top left until it fits perfectly.

Comment: I just followed the answer i posted originally on my question...it works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **two** `PictureBoxes` and bring **one below** the `DGV` and **nest the other**. Then move the overlay to the right place..
both should be identical otherwise, i.e. have the same `Image` and the same `SizeMode`.

Here is a function that'll do it:

```
void overlayCtls(Control ctlBase, Control ctlOverlay, Control ctlTgt )
{
    ctlOverlay.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    ctlOverlay.Parent = ctlTgt;
    ctlOverlay.Location = new Point(ctlBase.Left - ctlTgt.Left, ctlBase.Top - ctlTgt.Top);
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Notes:

- You explictily need to do the nesting as a DGV is not a container, so it will not be enough to move it in place in the designer.
- You explictily need to set the BackColor to Transparent even if it was set in the designer. Looks like it will be taken from the parent unless set in code.
- The nested child control will overlay not only the `ClientArea` of its `Parent` but also any `Border`.

Comment: Cool....this is what i wanted...:) Just to get it correct i will create 2 pictureboxes with identical sizes ...the 1 being dummy and the 1 containing the image...the dummy will be parented to the DGV and the one with the image to the dummy? and then run the method...can you give a little more info..

Comment: Yes. But both should have the same image and also the same properties like size and sizemode!

Comment: So essentially you have 2 pictureboxes...one child of the control in question and one just under the control...the control child is clipped to the boundaries of the control and the 2nd picturebox just "fills" the rest...

Comment: Exactly. Do you get it to work?  (Of course you don't really need a reusable function if you have only one such overlay..)

Comment: Well something in the positioning is giving me a bit of headache but i will work it out...thanks...for the clever idea