# Can't make rounded PictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a problem to round a picturebox's edges on visual studio enterprise 2015. I am using this code:

```
private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
    gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width - 3, pictureBox1.Height - 3);
    Region rg = new Region(gp);
    pictureBox1.Region = rg;
}
```

Nothing happens when I run this code..

Comment: I'd suggest reading the Help Center, starting with http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this way once I think it would work.

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
int d = 50;
gp.AddArc(r.X, r.Y, d, d, 180, 90);
gp.AddArc(r.X + r.Width - d, r.Y, d, d, 270, 90);
gp.AddArc(r.X + r.Width - d, r.Y + r.Height - d, d, d, 0, 90);
gp.AddArc(r.X, r.Y + r.Height - d, d, d, 90, 90);
pictureBox1.Region = new Region(gp);
```

Comment: I made it and worked! But the edge of the pictureBox is too much rounded.

Answer (score 0):

The code works just fine.

But you may be mixing up `pictureBox1` and `pictureBox3`.

Or maybe the click event is not [hooked up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=1|0.3898#33276161)
..

For using a **rounded rectangle** instead of an **ellipse** look at Neel's answer!