# Using checkboxes to delete lines off line graph

Tags: c#, checkbox, graph, charts

I have a graph that has lines plotted on it from different lists. 
I have added several checkboxes and used if statements to check if the checkbox is clicked. Like so:

```
public Form1()
{           
    InitializeComponent();
    CreateGraph();
    this.Text = "HRM File Analyser";

    if (hrCheck.Checked)
    {
        drawHR();
        chart1.Update();
    }
    else if (!hrCheck.Checked)
    {
        chart1.Series["Heart Rate"].Points.Clear();
        chart1.Update();
    }
}
```

However, even after calling the update method nothing changes at all.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is the else condition functioning properly? Can you show the contents of drawHR()?

Comment: Also, are these checkboxes declared on this form? If so, you can't use their check-state in a conditional expression in the form's constructor. You would want to add a checked event handler for the checkboxes and put your conditional code in there.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with the code you show us is that is seems to be interactive but everything (we see) really happens only once upon startup.

- Instead you should code the `CheckChanged` event of the `Checkbox`! (You get to it by double-clicking the checkbox in the designer..)
- Next I suggest not to clear away i.e. **delete** all the data. Instead simply **disable** the series. Now you can turn the series off or on..
- The checkbox checking logic is also overblown; one check will be sufficient!

So the new and improved version would look like this:

```
public Form1()
{           
    InitializeComponent();
    CreateGraph();
    this.Text = "HRM File Analyser";
    hrCheck_CheckedChanged(null, null);   // set initial state
    ..
}

private void hrCheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series["Heart Rate"].Enabled = hrCheck.Checked;
}
```

If you didn't create it by double-clicking, do not forget to [hook up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=1|0.3901#33276161)  the `hrCheck_CheckedChanged` event!