# Hoe to reach a system function in c#

Tags: c#, function, charts, customization, designer

I used a chart1_Customize function in my program , but the program don't reach it. Am I supposed to change something in the designer?

Here's the function:

```
      private void chart1_Customize (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (CustomLabel lbl in chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels)
        {
            lbl.Text = range[count];
            count++;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Where do you want to reach this function from?

Comment: This is an event, did you subscribe to it anywhere?

Comment: I don't know how to subscribe to it.

Comment: See here for a smal tutorial on [hooking up events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=1|0.3900#33276161)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help [Customizing a chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456612.aspx), in this example the event is added during the pageload, i suppose u have to do something similar?
Or look if the event is wired to your function in the properties section of your chart [image]