# If the cursor is in a specific textBox, delete only that textBox text with a button click

Tags: c#, textbox, buttonclick, cursor-position

I am building a simple calculator. I have three textBoxes: textBox1 (first operand), textBox2 (second operand), and textBox3 (result). I have numerous operand functions that can be performed. I also have a button that will clear all fields, as well as other functions.

I am having difficulty with the code needed to delete the text in a specific textbox with a button only when the cursor is in that textbox.

Ex: if cursor is in textBox1, the button only clears that textbox.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `Button` is clicked it will gain focus.

So you need to keep track of which of your `TextBoxes` got focus **last**.

Create a class level variable for that:

```
TextBox focusedTextBox = null;
```

Now [hook up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=1|0.3901#33276161) this event with the `Enter` event **of all three** `TextBoxes`:

```
private void textBoxes_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    focusedTextBox = sender as TextBox;
}
```

Then this will only clear the one your user was in last:

```
private void buttonClearCurrent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (focusedTextBox != null) focusedTextBox.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was having a problem with. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to use the Focused property in the textbox.
But you need to make a loop to identify which text box is focused.

like:

```
var focusedControl;
foreach(var control in this.Controls)
{
    if(control is TextBox)
    {
        if(control.Focused)
        {
           focusedControl = control;
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work when clicking the Button. He needs to keep track before!

Comment: Yep...you are right...your solution is a better way..thx..=D @Taw

Answer (score 0):

You can use event: "MouseHover" or "MouseClick" and set textBox1.Text=""