# C# one combobox with imagelist change with switch working, but others are not

Tags: c#, combobox, switch-statement, imagelist

I have four combo boxes where I want an image to change (along with another two lines of code) when they are changed on selection. The one for Desks (comDesks) works. That's the one I did first. Then I cut and pasted the rest. As far as I can see I changed everything correctly for the other three. When I run the program and change the combo box for chairs, comps, or stations the picture does not change. I used imageLists for each one with a swich statement. REMEMBER that the desks works, it's the first one I wrote EVEN THOUGH it's the second section of code after chairs. (ADDED May 4th: I cut and pasted the switch statement, I did not cut and paste the event. The event is linked properly as far as I can tell.) Here is my code:

```
private void comChairs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // switch statement for selection change
    switch (comChairs.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            // Change image
            pbxChairs.Image = imgChairs.Images[0];
            // Set price to variable used later
            chairCost = 90.00m;
            // Set description to variable used later
            chairString = comChairs.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        case 1:
            pbxChairs.Image = imgChairs.Images[1];
            chairCost = 135.00m;
            chairString = comChairs.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        case 2:
            pbxChairs.Image = imgChairs.Images[2];
            chairCost = 220.00m;
            chairString = comChairs.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void comDesks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comDesks.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            pbxDesks.Image = imgDesks.Images[0];
            deskCost = 450.00m;
            deskString = comDesks.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        case 1:
            pbxDesks.Image = imgDesks.Images[1];
            deskCost = 650.00m;
            deskString = comDesks.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        case 2:
            pbxDesks.Image = imgDesks.Images[2];
            deskCost = 1000.00m;
            deskString = comDesks.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void comComps_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comComps.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            pbxComps.Image = imgComps.Images[0];
            compCost = 849.00m;
            compString = comComps.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        case 1:
            pbxComps.Image = imgComps.Images[1];
            compCost = 1250.00m;
            compString = comComps.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        case 2:
            pbxComps.Image = imgComps.Images[2];
            compCost = 1799.00m;
            compString = comComps.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void comStations_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comStations.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            pbxStations.Image = imgStations.Images[0];
            stationCost = 1250.00m;
            stationString = comStations.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        case 1:
            pbxStations.Image = imgStations.Images[1];
            stationCost = 1450.00m;
            stationString = comStations.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        case 2:
            pbxStations.Image = imgStations.Images[2];
            stationCost = 2500.00m;
            stationString = comStations.SelectedItem.ToString();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your event assigned on the Control?

Comment: You need to [__hook up__ the event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=2|0.3896#33276161) , not just copy it

Comment: The event is assigned as far as I can tell. I did NOT cut and paste the event code, I only cut and pasted the switch statement.