# C# - Chart cursor not following mousepoint value

Tags: c#, charts

I have this issue where my chart cursor X is not following the mouse Point.

I have the code like this,

```
private void TrendChart_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
   Point mousePoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
   TrendChart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint, true);
   TrendChart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint, true);
 }
```

The result is like this :

[image: My mouse is at left there but x cursor (vertical red line is at right)]

Do you have any idea what could be the reason it's not following where my mouse is?

Comment: Very strange. Does the x position change or is it always where it is? Does the y-position work correctly? If none change the MouseMove is probably not [hooked up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=14|0.0000#33276161)

Comment: @TaW i manage to get the Cursor X working. It is by making Interval = 0.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems? If so, do accept your own answer so the question doesn't look unresolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the flaws. Have to change a Chart property: Cursor X Interval to be 0. Mine was Interval = 1.

[image: ChartAreas properties]

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.cursor.interval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _A value of zero, which is the default value, signifies that a cursor or range selection can be drawn anywhere within a chart area. A nonzero value signifies that the cursor or beginning and/or end points of a selected range will only be drawn at the specified interval_ - I am not so sure about the claim that `0` is the default; I found it to be `1` for my chart..

Comment: @TaW thanks. I'm not sure why should change to 0. Because other chart I found also using 1 and have no problem with the cursor.

Comment: Well that will depend on the data. If they go 1,2,3,4...100 it will work fine. But if they go 0,0.1,0.2,0.3...1 it won't work at all.