# C# MouseDown event on a User Control that's inside another User Control

Tags: c#, winforms

**Update**: Remade the project and it started working.

---

I have a Windows Form that looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to make a `MouseDown` event for each `box`. As you can see, the `BigBox` user control has a `Panel` and a `TableLayoutPanel` on top of the Panel. Inside each cell of the `TableLayoutPanel` there is a user control called `MyBox`, which is just a picture box.

When I try to do a `MouseDown` event for `box1`, nothing happens. I have this code inside `BigBox.cs`:

```
namespace TestProject.controls
{
    public partial class BigBox : UserControl
    {
        public BigBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void box1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Box1 clicked.");
        }
    }
}
```

The console never prints anything. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to C# so I don't fully understand everything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you attach `box1_MouseDown` handler to the `MouseDown` event?

Comment: It is going to be hard to get a MouseDown, you leave hardly any space to click since you covered the panel with the TLP.  You would have to click at the edge, in practice there probably isn't any.  This does not need to be fixed.

Comment: I've never done any code for attaching something. Is that just going to the Events tab in the Properties box and making sure the it's listed there? If so, I did attach it. @HansPassant I'm not sure what you mean. Isn't clicking the whole cell enough space? I dock `MyBox` so it covers the whole cell.

Comment: To make sure if you attached the event handler, it's enough to select your `box1` and then in properties wiindow in events tab make sure `box1_MouseDown` is written in fron of `MouseDown`. Then your event is handled. Also if you overrided `OnMouseDown` in `MyBox` user control, then make sure you called `base.OnMouseDown(e);`.

Comment: I see. `box1_MouseDown` is inside the events tab for `MouseDown`. So it should be handled. I don't have any kind of events inside `MyBox`.

Comment: So let me know when you say *The console never prints anything.* What do you mean by *The console*? Which window did you check?

Comment: The `output` window.

Comment: Did you set *Show output from* to *Debug*?

Comment: When I do `Console.Write()` anywhere else, say the constructor of `BigBox`, it prints out whatever I write inside `Console.Write()` to the `output` window. Not sure what you mean to set it.

Comment: You see a combo box at top of the output window, the selected value should be *Debug*. If you checked all of these, then you need to post a code to reproduce the problem. Currently the question and the comments are like a guess game.

Comment: Oh ok, it was set to Debug. You want to see the Designer code? Not sure what else to post as the `MouseDown` event is the only thing I added.

Comment: ummm why not just use MessageBox.Show(<message Here>)....that way it will just pop open a window instead of you looking for the console window.....

Comment: So the MessageBox wasn't showing up either. Nothing I wrote in the `MouseDown` method was working. I remade the whole project and it started working. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Flow How did you create the `MouseDown` eventhandler?

Comment: See here for hints on how to [hook up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=14|0.0000#33276161) events! You should also look into creating the PictureBoxes dynamically, so you don't have to repeat any code 20 times. That goes for the MouseDown code as well!!!

Answer (score 0):

use `console.Writeline` that prints it to the console line.

Comment: This still doesn't print anything.