# Changing a ChartType from Polar to Radar

Tags: c#, charts, mschart, radar-chart

I asked in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940752/set-a-c-sharp-polar-diagram-to-a-specific-amout-of-rings-and-segments) how to set a specific number of rings and sectors for a polar diagram . I now have a button which changes the chart from polar to radar. The problem is the number of segments changes from 24 (correct) to 25 (wrong). I have no idea why.

The code to set the number of rings:

```
#region chartdesign
Series s = chartleft.Series[0];            // a reference to the default series
ChartArea ca = chartleft.ChartAreas[0];  // a reference to the default chart area
Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Polar;   // set the charttype of the series

s.Points.AddXY(0,0);
ax.Interval = 15;
ay.Interval = 1;

ax.IntervalOffset = 0;
ax.Minimum = 0;
ax.Maximum = 360;

ay.IntervalOffset = 0;
ay.Minimum = 0;
ay.Maximum = 10;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
Series s2 = chartright.Series[0];            // a reference to the default series
ChartArea ca2 = chartright.ChartAreas[0];  // a reference to the default chart area
Axis ax2 = ca2.AxisX;
Axis ay2 = ca2.AxisY;
s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Polar;   // set the charttype of the series

// a few data to test:

s2.Points.AddXY(0, 0);

ax2.Interval = 15;
ay2.Interval = 1;

ax2.IntervalOffset = 0;
ax2.Minimum = 0;
ax2.Maximum = 360;

ay2.IntervalOffset = 0;
ay2.Minimum = 0;
ay2.Maximum = 10;
#endregion
```

[image: image: polar]
[image: image: Radar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Polar` and `Radar` charts look rather similar, but they really are **quite different**.

As you saw, in a `Polar` chart you can influence the number of segments by setting the relevant X-Axis properties.

Most important are the `Maximum` and the `Interval`.

`Radar` is **different**: It basically works like an **indexed** chart. This means that all points are sitting at **equal distance** in a row (or rather a circle) completely **ignoring the x-values**.

This means that:

- The **number of segments** is equal to the **number of `DataPoints`**.
- The values for `XAxis.Maximum, -Minimum and -Interval` are ignored.
- No two `DataPoints` can share the same spot, even if their x-values are the same.

In your example you must have `25` datapoints, probably the first and last being equal. For the `Polar` chart these will sit at the **same** spot but for the Radar chart they sit **beside** each other, hence you see one more segment.

Let me clone the first point and add it to the end:

```
s.Points.Add(s.Points.First().Clone());
```

You can see it even better if you add colors to the first and the last `DataPoint`:

```
s.Points.First().Color =  Color.Orange;
s.Points.Last().Color = Color.Red;
```

Now you can see one colored line segment in the `Polar` chart but two colored datapoint segments in the `Radar` chart:

[image][image]

You can also see that I have added `12+1` `DataPoints` to the `Chart`. The first and last coincide in the `Polar` chart but sit beside each other in the `Radar` chart.

Comment: Thank you. As soon as you said that the Radar diagram completes itself I knew what I did wrong. Thank you so much.