# How to call a Paint method from a Click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

The issue I am having is, I cannot get the "e.Graphics" lines of code to work if I try to use them in a button1_Click method.  So, I have constructed "Paint" method.  Now I can't seem to call the Paint method from the button Click event.
Is there a way to do this?  I have not been able to find a way to make this work.
Or, is there a way to do the e.Graphics functions in the "button1_Click" method?

Thank you

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrochetPtrnDesign_Paint(this, ?);
    }

    private void CrochetPtrnDesign_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(5, 5,
            ClientSize.Width - 10, ClientSize.Height - 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect);

        using (Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 16, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
        {
            using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
            {
                // Middle.
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;  // Middle.

                // Middle/Center.
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;      // Center.
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Middle/Center", font, Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you do something like: `CrochetPtrnDesign_Paint(this, new PaintEventArgs(...))`?

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin No this will not work as it will never have a truely valid Graphics object.. Instead he must trigger the `Paint` by doing this: `CrochetPtrnDesign.Invalidate();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Case One: Drawing onto `Controls`:

Provided the `Paint` event is actually **hooked up** and not just a piece of code you have copied, this will do the job:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrochetPtrnDesign.Invalidate();
}
```

**Update**: since we now know that `CrochetPtrnDesign` is the `Form` simply write: `this.Invalidate();`!

If in doubt about [hooking up read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=14|0.0000#33276161)!

Note that creating truely valid `PaintEventArgs` should only be done by the system..

### Case Two: Drawing into Bitmaps:

To draw into a `Bitmap` you also need a valid `Graphics` object, but you have to create it yourself:

```
void DrawStuff(Bitmap bmp)
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        // draw your stuff
        g.DrawRectangle(...);
    }
    // when done maybe assign it back into a Control..
    pictureBox.Image = bmp;
}
```

**Update:**

Assigning the bitmap to the `pictureBox.Image` will work but runs the risk of leaking the previous image. To avoid this you can use a faile-safe method, maybe like this:

```
void SetImage(PictureBox pb, Bitmap bmp)
{
    if (pb.Image != null)
    {
        Bitmap tmp = (Bitmap)pb.Image;
        pb.Image = null;
        tmp.Dispose();
    }
    pb.Image = bmp;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I cannot get the "e.Graphics" lines of code to work if I try to use them in a button1_Click method

That's by design. You're not supposed to be drawing anything while handling the `Click` event. So calling the `Paint` event handler is, at the very least, inconvenient.

The right way to do this would be to call `Invalidate()` while handling `Click`, and then let Windows decide when to call your `Paint` event handler. If something should be drawn differently as a result of the `Click` event, then the `Click` event handler should update your data to indicate this, so that later when the `Paint` event handler is called, it knows exactly what to draw at that time.