# Datagridview event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `dataGridView` and I am trying to fire an event when a cell is clicked.I have tried using the following events with no avail:

```
    private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    { 
     //dosomething
    }
```

```
    private void dataGridView2_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    { 
     //dosomething 
    }

    private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    { 
     //dosomething 
    }

    private void dataGridView2_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    { 
     //dosomething 
    }

    private void dataGridView2_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    { 
     //dosomething 
    }
```

I made sure the `dataGridView`'s name matched, but none of these events are firing or showing up in the debugger. Am I missing something?

Comment: Matching the name is not important, make sure you attached the event handler method to the event using code or using designer.

Comment: I think you're missing the part where you actually hook up the events. It doesn't magically attach the event because you have the name of the control, an underscore, then the event name. Like @RezaAghaei suggested, use the designer or do it in code.

Comment: Odd, I've never had to hook it up before. I've always typed it out and it has just worked.

Comment: _I've always typed it out and it has just worked._ nonsense! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=14|0.0000#33276161) to learn more about hooking up events! – TaW 5 mins ago

Comment: It may be nonsense to you, but I have not had to hook up the event before, and I have been using C# for 4-5 years.

Comment: You were clearly missing something as it is impossible for an event to fire without being hooked to a handler one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the grid in designer, goto properties, click events button in the properties and double click on the value cell on the right of CellClick event
OR
Goto designer.cs file and look where all properties of gridview are defined and see if any line like this is present

gridview.CellClick += new EventHandler(dataGridView2_CellClick);

If it isnt present then add it.