# how to condense multiple mouse enters and leaves

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So i'm using a panel as a button. fairly easy but i have 3 or so labels in the panel and i have around 9 of these panel buttons. how can i make it a little easier than writing mouse enter and leave methods for each item?. if they where identical i would use a user control but there all different but i want the panels to be same colour on enter(silver) and the same on leave (green).

something like

if mouseenter panel1,label1,label2,label3
{
 panel1 silver 
}
if that makes any sense

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can map them to the same event handler and there discern them by the `sender` param..

Comment: iv never used event handlers or senders  but from what iv seen isnt that just about the same amount of code ?

Comment: _iv never used event handlers or senders_ __Of course you have!__ By double clicking an event in the events pane of a control you have a) created and event handler (e.g. `private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`) and hooked it up with the actual event (`button9.Click +=  button9_Click;` in the designer.cs file) See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=14|0.0000#33276161) for more on this. This is basic c# coding knowledge. Do not miss it as it is essential! Several controls' events can be hooked up to the same handler!

Comment: i mean iv never used them "manually" but i did a quick test with a few random panels and labels and its worked perfect :D