# Update button for GridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm trying to create an Update button to let me insert data into a gridview and after creating the class, the button does nothing and I don't understand why that is the case.

```
private void Basic()
{
    // no updates allowed
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;

    //UpdateButton is available

    UpdateButton.Enabled = true;

    //Save and Cancel Unavailable

    SaveButton.Visible = false;
    CancelButton.Visible = false;

    sTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet1.S);
}
```

This is the UpdateButton Event

```
private void UpdateButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;

    UpdateButton.Enabled = false;

    SaveButton.Visible = true;
    CancelButton.Visible = true;
}
```

And this should be the update class:

```
this.UpdateButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 63);
this.UpdateButton.Name = "UpdateButton";
this.UpdateButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 23);
this.UpdateButton.TabIndex = 0;
this.UpdateButton.Text = "Update";
this.UpdateButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

The connection is made with a accdb. 
The Update button isn't working on click, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Well this is not an update button `class`, it is the button click `event handler`...
The second thing - what is your exact question?

Comment: Can you debug click event of update button?

Comment: Hmmm… where is the code for the `UpdateButton_Click` event? Without this event… as you said… _"the button does nothing"_

Comment: How should I add it?

Comment: Double click on the button in design view and it will create it for you.

Comment: I have one there but it doesn't do anything, will post it

Comment: There is nothing in the click event code that updates the `DataGridView`, `DataTable` or the “database” with new data. The code appears to simply allow the user to add new rows of data to the `DataGridView`. What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: I was expecting it to let me add rows and then with another button save the changes into the DB. Kind of an add button actually.

Comment: After you click the update button, this does not happen? Is there a new blank row at the bottom of the `DataGridView` after you click this update button?

Comment: No, nothing happens, it's a blank click, no new row.

Comment: Found the solution, after double-clicking and creating another UpdateButton_Click_1 (that's the name it gave itself) and introduced the code from UpdateButton_Click inside it worked.

Comment: That will do it

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. - You should study this post on [hooking up events]
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=14|0.0000#33276161)