# Events are not firing in Docked Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a panel at top with the dock option 'Top' However events are not firing like;

```
    private void pnlHeader_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
```

[image: Added event]

Red area where i click
[image]

All others panels are working good which they all are docked too.

What should be the cause?

Comment: The usual cause is that the event(s) is/are not [hooked up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=14|0.0000#33276161) - Check in the properties-events pane! - Another could be that it is covered.

Comment: @TaW no, all of this done already. Still same.

Comment: To be sure you can also give it a Backcolor and do a BringToFront in a test button click. Can you add a button to it and click the button? Also test the size of the panel!

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing on the panel that is hiding it and getting the clicks?

Comment: I did what you said, all of the same. Also edited question. @TaW

Comment: There is however, their size is obvious. I added an image.@Jcl

Comment: Hm, and when you click the panel in the desiger it shows up? Sounds strange!

Comment: @TaW yes, its all strange.

Comment: Last resort usually is removing the fishy control and replacing it with a fresh one. emove the buttons from it first, of course. then test the new one, then move the buttons back. if that helped the curious one might want to study the old deisgner.ce file with the new one..

Comment: Are you using uwp or wpf? or even dockpanel suite?

Answer (score 1):

If your Panel contains other elements, and you're clicking on these elements, then the MouseClick event won't be fired (I just tested that).
The solution is to whether put the same MouseClick event on the inner elements, or laying an invisible surface on the Panel in order to get the MouseClick event.

Comment: this is not the answer.

Comment: OK, but please don't donwvote, because this was a legitimate try. And I'm stuggling to get reputation