# C# Winform MouseEnter Event is not working

Tags: c#, mouseenter

I'm trying to use the `MouseEnter` event in C# using WinForms. However, `MouseEnter` event does not work.

```
private void button3_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("123");
}
```

Comment: what doesnt work for you? it does work for me...

Comment: Is it [Hooked up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=1|0.3901#33276161)