# How to open "openFileDialog" by button click?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, openfiledialog

I would like to open the *openFileDialog* at the click of a **button**. But all my efforts are unsuccessful.

I tried this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {
                Class1 excel = new Class1(dialog.InitialDirectory, 1);
                string path = dialog.InitialDirectory + ".txt"; //this is to create a text document with the same name
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);

                tw.Write(excel.ReadCell(0, 0));
                tw.Close();
            }
        }
```

There always seems to be something going on but the window disappears right away.

Does anyone know your advice?

Thanks

Comment: Probably the property DialogResult for that button is not set to None.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - _the window disappears right away_ Really??? You should set up the dialog befor you show it but it should show just fine. Of course the stuff you later do will not show.. - __And__ you need to use the `dialog`, not some `openFileDialog1` !!

Comment: @Steve *DialogResult* is set to None

Comment: @TaW Is it better?

Comment: This line _string path = dialog.InitialDirectory + ".txt";_ is giving you a filename to write with the name of the directory with appended the .txt extension. It doesn't seems correct. Side note. Could you explain what is disappearing?

Comment: Looks even better. But still the dialog ought to show up in any case. Do us all a favor and use your best friend, the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)!

Comment: @Steve Side note is added, the window that pops up is very fast so I don't even know if it's an *openfiledialog*

Comment: @TaW with debugger I´m not good freind :( in my language isnť good instructions unfortunately

Comment: Then now is the time to learn it! Really !! Just add a breakpoint at the line with the showdialog and step once.. To set a breakpoint click at the grey part to the left of the line number. It will creat a dark red circle.. - To step press F11 !

Comment: @TaW okey I try  it, thank you!

Comment: @TaW  when i click on f11 it throws me into program.cs, is it ok?

Comment: You did set the beakpoint? and then started the program? If not press F5 ! Now your button should come up and when you click it the debugger should stop at the breakpoint..

Comment: @TaW Yes my button showed up when I clicked on it nothing happened,
I guess it's supposed to show where the debbuger read the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225162/discussion-between-taw-and-userdavid).

Comment: Is the click event [Hooked up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275763/copy-datagridview-values-to-textbox/33276161?s=1|0.3901#33276161)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this.

```
            using (OpenFileDialog upload = new OpenFileDialog())
                {
                    upload.Filter = "Txt Files|*.txt";
                    upload.Title = "Select File";
                    if (upload.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                        return;
                    string filePath= upload.FileName;
                    this.fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                }
```

Comment: it is set only filter for *openfiledialog*

Comment: Also use using statement. This code work for me when i need to open file dialog from button click. I thoutht maybe problem was using statement.